# Power Query - Keeping Most recent records in change log columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I need to strip records to show just the most recent for a given person, and I'm trying to think of a method for doing this in a custom column so I can just keep the most recent records. This is essentially a a status change list, and I need to match the last change as a "current status" for merging with another query. Each date can be unique, and each person can have any from 1 to a dozen status changes. I've picked a selection below, Last Names have been removed to protect the innocent. For sake of the example, Each "name" has a unique identifier that I can use to prevent any overlap from similar names.

```
 AaronS 4/1/2015
 AaronS 10/16/2013
 AaronS 5/15/2013
 AdamS  2/27/2007
 AdamL  12/16/2004
 AdamL  11/17/2004
 AlanG  11/1/2007
 AlexanderJ 7/1/2016
 AlexanderJ 1/25/2016
 AlexanderJ 4/1/2015
 AlexanderJ 10/16/2013
 AlexanderJ 6/1/2013
 AlexanderJ 11/7/2011
```

My goal would be to return the most recent date for each individual "name" and nulls for the other rows. Then I can filter out nulls to return one row per name. I'm fairly new to power query and mostly adept with the UI, barely learning M Code. Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: Would a "Group by" the "name" column and get the MAX of the status change date would solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

### GUI

1. Bring the "Name" and "Date" data into Power Query.
2. Group by "Name".  In the Group By dialog select the operation **All Rows**.  Name the new column "AllRows". Click OK.
3. Add a custom column and title it "LatestRow". Enter the formula below.  Click OK.  Note that the "Date" column is coming from the sub-table in the "AllRows" column.

```
= Table.Max([AllRows], "Date")
```

4. Click the expand button in the upper right corner of the "LatestRow" column.  This will return the record associated with the latest date for each name.

### Code

```
let
    Source            = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="data"]}[Content],
    GroupedRows       = Table.Group(Source, {"Name"}, {{"AllRows", each _, type table [Name=nullable text, Date=nullable datetime]}}),
    AddedCustomColumn = Table.AddColumn(GroupedRows, "LatestRow", each Table.Max([AllRows], "Date")),
    ExpandedLatestRow = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(AddedCustomColumn, "LatestRow", {"Date"}, {"LatestRow.Date"})
in
    ExpandedLatestRow
```